# CSS selector priority in color

Tags: css, colors, css-selectors

**I think 'WEB' must be PINK
because *h1 selector* is under the *a selector*..
Why is it Black??**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WEB - CSS</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    a {
      color:black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    h1 {
      color:pink;
      font-size:45px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Because 'a' is more specific

Answer (score 0):

You have explicitly set your link's color to black. By default, a link will inherit its color from its parent element. But in your case, where you have specifically set its color, it will use the color you set it to.

Note that your are not overriding your link's color property by specifying a color to its parent element. You are setting the link's parent element's color, not the link's color itself. If you use `h1 a` instead of `a` as the selector, then in this case you will be overriding your link's color property and will hence appear in a pink color, as in the below snippet.

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 a {
  color: pink;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="index.html">WEB</a></h1>
```